# problem formatting php output

Tags: php

I have a php website that I want to use to gather information from a unix server. A good example would be a script that would ssh into a server and run an ls command. I am having problems formatting the output so it is readable. Any help would be appreciated. The code would look something like this:

```
$output = system("ssh user@testServer ls -al");
print ($output);
```

Comment: Show some example output please.

Comment: Is PHP running as a server module. In that case see my answer, it addresses the problem.

Answer (score 7):

you probably want to use

```
echo "<pre>";
echo system("ssh user@testServer ls -al");
echo "</pre>";
```

which shows code in $output as-is (3 spaces shows as 3 spaces, a new line shows as a new line)

Comment: This does not work, as `system()` automatically flushes the PHP output after each line from shell is recieved. To properly format the output, you must do `echo '<pre>'` before the call to `system()`, as I have done in my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this

> The system() call also tries to automatically flush the web server's
>   output buffer after each line of output if PHP is running as a server
>   module.

So you need to do this like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
$output = system("ssh user@testServer ls -al");
echo '</pre>';
```

**Alternative**
As suggested by Deebster, if you have `exec` function enabled on your server you can do this like this also

```
$output = null;
exec("ssh user@testServer ls -al", $output);
echo '<pre>';
foreach($output as $line)
    echo $line . "\n";
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Alternatively, using exec() like ```exec('ssh user@testServer ls -al', $output);``` would give you an array of the output, without having to produce spaghetti code

Answer (score 0):

Try using [htmlspecialchars()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape anything that will cause rendering problems in HTML:

`print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($output) . '</pre>';`

The pre tag will respect whitespace and defaults to a monospaced font so your lines will look like they would in a console.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I guess it will work
since php doc says

> The system() call also tries to automatically flush the web server's
>   output buffer after each line of output if PHP is running as a server
>   module.

```
ob_start();
system("ssh user@testServer ls -al");

$output = ob_get_clean();

echo '<pre>';
echo $output; 
echo '</pre>';
```